# sublime text 2 doesnot restore open files after restart

Tags: linux, centos, sublimetext2

I am using sublime text 2 (version 2.0.2) editor on cent os 6.5. Recently I started facing many issues, but one major issue is it does not remember the open files after closing and opening the editor window. Earlier it used to not only remember open files but also unsaved edits, after testing online suggestions I still could not resolve this issue, any suggestions would be of great help.

```
"hot_exit": false,
"remember_open_files": true,
"create_window_at_startup": true,
```

these are my current parameters in Preferences -> Settings - Default

Answer (score -1):

I could solve this issue myself following this helpful link [Reverting to fresh install state](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/revert.html). Although that link has not worked for me, I just deleted sublime_plugin.py from my /opt/Sublime Text 2 directory then it works fine. So it seems that sublime starts misbehaving after adding new packages. In fact, I had deleted everything inside ~/.config/sublime-text-2 before sublime_plugin.py (it did not help though) not sure whether that is required, not to mention you can try after taking a backup

Comment: Hope you have gone through the link I included, In most (may not be all) cases sublime starts misbehaving after adding plug-in's (which i did), I just removed it so it worked, if you have read my comment fully, I never said its THE or ONLY solution. Trying it is NOT really an awful idea since its not going harm anything else, but will definitely save a lot of time if it works, which it did for me.

Comment: I apologize for  sublime_plugin.py and repeating in above comment, with out checking. I now realized that my sublime_plugin.pyc was still existing. So I think deleting ~/.config/sublime-text-2 conents has helped me. But certainly my solution is NOT awful and it really took me to initial state of new sublime with all working functionalities.